# Swing Mouse scroll does not scroll drop down menu

Tags: java, swing, events, scrollbar, mouseevent

I am trying to scroll down a drop down box. Altough mouseWheelListener is invoked, scrollBar is not moved and dropdown box is just closed after scrool event. Problem  is value of scrollBar is not changed after setting in the event handler, it is always 0.

Here is the part of code:

```
public MyClas extends JPopupMenu implements AdjustmentListener, ContainerListener, ChangeListener{
  public MyClass(){
    .....
    setLayout(new ScrollablePopupMenuLayout(this, defaultWidth));
    JScrollBar scrollBar = new JScrollBar(JScrollBar.VERTICAL);
    scrollBar.setFocusable(false);
    scrollBar.addAdjustmentListener(this);
    addContainerListener(this);
    addMouseWheelListener(new MouseWheelListener(){
         // Here is invoked after scrolling
         public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e){
         {
              int x = 1;
              scrollBar.setValue(scrollBar.getValue() + x)
         }

    });
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: What was the point of that edit? Where is the **MCVE / SSCCE?**

Comment: Why? Why not just use a JScrollPane

Comment: It is already written yearsa ago and needs more change to switch to JScrollPane.

Answer (score 0):

It worked after adding following line to the mouseWheelEvent method:

```
e.consume();
```